# Create Indexes on MongoDB when creating collection (Java)

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm currently working with MongoDB and its Java Driver. On top of this, I have REST webservices which allows client to create collection and push documents in MongoDB.

I want to automatically create indexes on specific, mandatory fields in Mongo. First, I took a look at [ensureIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/), only to see that it was deprecated, and method [createIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex) is now recommended.

So I could make a pretty simple method like this :

```
private void setCollection(String collection) {
        this.collection = mongoDB.getDataBase().getCollection(collection);
        this.collection.createIndex("key");
}
```

According to [behaviors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#behaviors) of indexes, the method createIndex() will not rebuild an existing index.

So my question is : is my method elegant ? Is createIndex() making a additionnal call to MongoDB to ensure that the index is already created ? Which could possibly lead to performance issue.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you index a collection that has just been created by the user I wouldn't care much about performance issues. It is probably empty, anyway, isnt' it? And for existing collections you don't have to check it, as you created the index at initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is, when I set the collection, I don't know if the collection is already there or not. My method setCollection() is called for every request on my REST services, so clients could request some old or new collections.

Comment: I don't really know, if I understood the problem. When you get the collection from Mongo, it will either be non-existent or already present. If non-existent you first create the collection and then, and only then, create the index. If already present, you just return the collection.

Comment: The problem is, when I call the getCollection() method from MongoDB driver, it will always return a collection, wether it exists or not. The driver will handle the creation of the collection itself if it have to. But maybe I can just call the createCollection() method, which will throw an exception if the collection already exists. If not, I could just create the collection and the index. I think that would work.

Comment: Oh right. Another idea apart from ``createCollection()`` and catching exceptions is to load the list of collection names initially from the database. If a collection is requested whose name is on your list, you return it straight away. If it's not on the list, you create the index and add its name to your list.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea too. I will try the two solutions and keep you updated. Thank you.

Comment: In a very similar situation we check the existing indexed via listIndexes() on the collection and only create the missing ones. I don't know whether this is optimal or even necessary in Mongo, but it works (and I have the relatively positive feeling of *not* calling createIndex when it is already there.)

Comment: I thought of that too, but listIndexes() will systematically make a call to the database, and will probably result in performance loss. But yes, it is more secure to not create an index every time.